# "abc"[0] not a compile-time constant

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, mingw

I have this code:

```
template< char... chars >
struct VariadicTemplate
{};


int
main()
{
    VariadicTemplate< "abc"[ 0 ], "abc"[ 1 ], "abc"[ 2 ] >  v;
}
```

This compiles fine with mingw-w64 4.8.1 . However, the same does not compile under MSVC 2013 nor the VC++ November CTP with an error:

> Error 1   error C2975: 'chars' : invalid template argument for 'VariadicTamplate', expected compile-time constant expression

Which of the "no"s or "partial"s refer to this?
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2013/12/02/c-11-14-core-language-features-in-vs-2013-and-the-nov-2013-ctp.aspx

If none, is this a compiler bug?

Comment: Curious, do you know if it does the same thing with a non-variadic template?

Comment: maybe just try `VariadicTemplate<'a', 'b', 'c'>`

Comment: I think this is just general `constexpr` support, which is known and listed as being incomplete.

Comment: well, c++ november CTP declares to have partial support for constexpr, except for member functions, which I think is not this case

Comment: @DaliborFrivaldsky It actually says "The CTP supports C++11 constexpr, except for member functions. (Another limitation is that arrays aren't supported.)" `"abc"` is an array of `const char`.

Comment: Yeah, I've just found it, thanks

Comment: Could you please write it as an answer so I can close it? Thank you

Comment: @DaliborFrivaldsky ecatmur already did so, I think it's okay to just accept his answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This change in behavior from C++03 to C++11 can be located in **5.19 Constant expressions** (same clause both standards).  As such, I suspect it would be covered by the *constexpr* no/partial.

Note that the paper given as reference for the *constexpr* feature, [n2235](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2235.pdf), is where the change to 5.19 was introduced:

> #### 4.5.3 Constant expressions revised
>
> **Paragraph modification.** Replace section 5.19 with [...]